# Cloning in a large DNA fragment into a plasmid

Tags: molecular-biology, cloning, plasmids

I need to clone in a 30kb DNA fragment into my plasmid (~7kb).

Working with such a large fragment I have run into  a few problems. The first was purifying it from the PCR mix used to amplify it out of its template, I achieved thsi with ethanol precipitation however I am unsure if thsi removes dNTPs from the PCR mix?

The second is ligating it into my plasmid. The fragment is flanked with EagI sites, however after digestion I cannot purify the digested fragment from the end cut fragments(due to its size).

I have two questions, firstly will the dNTPs remaining from the ethanol precipitation affect digestion and ligation reactions. Secondly will the end cut fragments affect ligation reactions.

Comment: Is your plasmid capable of handling such a huge insert? Most of the commonly used plasmids are not.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you please edit in some more information (the more the better for troubleshooting) - how big are your fragments from the EagI site digestion? How are you trying to separate the digested from undigested? Have you looked at things like Bacterial artificial chromosomes (BAC) that might be more appropriate for this size. What is the purpose of the cloning - expression, (cloning) library prep...?

Comment: Hello,

Yeah so my plasmid is a bit of a weird guy, its linear (has covalently closed ends) and has been demonstrated to be able to hold up to 40kb without too much problems. I've also further modified it to potentially make it hold more.

So the plasmid (being linear) has a left arm that it 5.7kb and a right arm that is 1.1kb; these are treated with EagI to leave overhangs. The fragments I am trying to clone in is 30kb and has eagi sites at each end.

Comment: So this plasmid is one which I have modified from a larger linear plasmid. The whole purpose of this is to be able to store and propagate large and complex DNA fragments without needing a very low copy number plasmid. The specific purpose of it is quite broad, and could be used for many purposes. Basically trying to demonstrate that my engineered plasmid can hold such large and complex fragments.

At the moment I'm assuming the fragment is being digested completely, and I am not doing a cleanup after because they don't seem to be able to cleanup such a large fragment.

Comment: The problems I'm encountering are about when I'm trying to ligate things into it, as this big 30kb fragment is hard to isolate using commercially avaliable PCR cleanup kits and so on.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to summarize the additional information you've provided in the comments. Comments are ephemeral and often overlooked so they should only be used for discussion of how to improve the associated post. I would suggest also including some information about the plasmid (with citations). Finally, you have multiple questions some of which I'm sure you can answer yourself — please edit this down to one clear question (make sure the title reflects that final question). That will help you get an answer and make this more useful to future users.

Comment: Please also take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details about how this site works and what is expected of users. This will help you get good answers (by asking well-formed, appropriate questions) and mitigate some of the frustration that new users often experience on SE sites.